# Arithmetic Calculator using Linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, arithmetic-expressions

I am using linked list to create a Calculator in C language.

Code:

**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
    int data;char str;
    struct node* next;
}node;
node* enter(node *h, int num){
    if(num==2){
        printf("enter operator");}
    else if(num==1){
        printf("Enter Number");
    }

    char input[20];
    fgets(input, 20, stdin);
    node *tmp = malloc(100);

    if(atoi(input)!=0){
        tmp->data = atoi(input);
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        tmp->str = (char)input[0];
        node *nodeNode = enter(tmp, num-1);
        tmp->next = nodeNode;
    }
}
int main(){
    node *head = malloc(100);
    char input[20];
    printf("Enter first num");
    fgets(input, 20, stdin);
    head->data = atoi(input);
    node *nextNode  = enter(head, 2);
    head->next = nextNode;

    int first = head->data;
    int second = head->next->next->data;
    char op =head->next->str;

    if(op == '+'){
        printf("%i + %i = %i", first, second, first+second);

    }
    else if(op == '-'){
        printf("%i - %i = %i", first, second, first-second);
    }
    else if(op == '*'){
        printf("%i * %i = %i", first, second, first*second);
    }
    else if(op == '/'){
        printf("%i / %i = %i", first, second, first/second);
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid operator or number");
    }
}
```

**

My Out needs to be like this:

```
Enter first Num: 10

Enter Operator: +

Enter Second Operator: 20

10 + 20 = 30.
```

well I am using online C compiler but getting Segmented fault error.
Program is running in repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/LimpingLightgoldenrodyellowGharial

Not running on other online compiler.
Please check and see is there any problem with Code?

Comment: Function `enter()` seems to return nothing, but declares that it returns pointer to struct. Maybe this is the beginning of the problems.

Comment: Which online compiler are you using? Your code is working fine on Linux.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: Program is working in different Compiler 
please check it on repl.it   https://repl.it/repls/LimpingLightgoldenrodyellowGharial

Comment: I want to know why is it having problems running in other compiler

Comment: A function that is declared to return a value **must** execute a `return` statement. Otherwise the behaviour is **undefined**. The compiler will tell you that if you ask it. **Always** use these gcc flags to compile: `-Wall -pedantic -Werror`.